# Disabling Options method in Javalin 3.0

Tags: api, kotlin, handler, request-headers, javalin

We are using Javalin in our kotlin application and we want to disable the **options** method from the handlers, We want to keep only **get,post** methods. below is the config code of Javalin

```
val app = Javalin.create {
          it.defaultContentType = "application/json"
          it.enableWebjars()
          it.addStaticFiles("", Location.CLASSPATH)
          it.enableCorsForAllOrigins()
          it.dynamicGzip = true
          it.showJavalinBanner = false
    }
```

I could not get 3.0 version documentation in the official website. is it in these lines to configure or some other place?

Comment: Docs for 3.x: https://javalin.io/archive/docs/v3.13.X.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding an explicit handler for this method with default 405 response:

```
app.options("/*") { throw MethodNotAllowedResponse() }
```